# making my multi-agent environment by deep reinforcement learning

Tags: deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning, multi-agent

I should make my own environment and apply **dqn** algorithm in a multi-agent environment.

I have **4 agents** . Each state of my environment has **5 variables** `state=[p1, p2, p3, p4,p5]`, at each time step,we update the different parameters of all states. Action is one of amount: `{-2,-1,0,1,2}` given the best q-value.

```
 param0,param1,param2,param3,param4=[[0 for x in range(numframe)] for y in range(number_nodes)] 

 `timestep p4[agent0]=random.randint(0,2)
  p4[agent1]=p4[agent0]+action
  p4[agent2]=p4[agent1]+action 
  p4[agent3]=p4[agent2]+action

 (actions find by a DNN in dqn and can be one of {-2,-1,0,1,2})`

param0..5=[[0 for x in range(numframe)] for y in range(number_nodes)]
```

numframe: shows amount for experience-replay, number_nodes=4 showing number of agents

I have written the following code based on [dqn-keras-code][1],

1- how I could change it to work as **multi-agent**?
2- how I could change to write my reset? (I should reset to `0`each of parameters)

I write some code but as I am beginner in dqn and multi-agent, I saw the following error: (I know it has also some problem related to multi-agent)

```
    line 156, in <module>
        state = env.reset()
    TypeError: reset() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Could you please help me more than this error how I can fix my **reset** section and **step** section?

Here is my code:

```
    import random
    import numpy as np
    import tensorflow as tf
    from collections import deque

    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import  Dense

    from keras.optimizers import Adam
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------
    global param0,param1,param2,param3,param4,state,next_state,action_space,action_size,w,m, reward,episodes,time_t,state
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------


    episodes=2000
    number_nodes=5 #one more than number of nodes
    timemax=500
    action_size=5
    state_size=5
    action_space=[-2,-1,0,1,2]
    m=16 #4*(ltime+ftime)=16
    numframe=16
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    class env:

        def __init__(self):

            self.action_space=[-2,-1,0,1,2] # X=[-2,2]
            self.action_size = len(self.action_space)

            self.state = None

            return action_space, action_size  

        def reset(self):
            #self.action_space=[0,0,0,0,0]
            for ii in range (1,4): #both sides
                param1[ii]=0
                param2[ii]=0
                param3[ii]=0
                param4[ii]=0
                param0[ii]=0
                reward[ii]=0

            state[ii]=[param0[ii],param1[ii],param2[ii],param3[ii],param4[ii]]
            return state

        # def reset(self):
            # self.state = self.np_random.uniform(low=-0.05, high=0.05, size=(4,))
            # self.steps_beyond_done = None
            # return np.array(self.state)

        def step(self,action):
            state = self.state
            param1, param2, param3, param4, param0 = state

            param0[0]=random.randint(0,2) #produce a random param0
            #relationship between parameteres for refreshing
            param0[1]=param0[0]+action
            param0[2]=param0[1]+action
            param0[3]=param0[2]+action
            param0[4]=param0[3]+action

            for i in range (1,4):
                param1[time_t][i]=param4[time_t][i+1]-param0[i+1]

                #action[i]=agent.init(state_size, action_size)
                #relationship between parameteres for refreshing
                param2[time_t][i]=param0[i]+action
                param3[time_t][i]=param2[time_t][i]
                param4[time_t][i]=param3[time_t][i]    
                #param1,param3,param4,param0


            next_state[i]=[param1[time_t][i],param2[time_t][i],param3[time_t][i],param4[time_t][i],param0[i]]

            cp= [2, 0, 0, 0]
            ch= [2, 2, 2, 2]
            # reward function
            if param1[i]>=0:
                reward[i]+=ch[i]*param1[time_t][i]

            else:
                reward[i]+=cp[i]*param1[time_t][i]


            return next_state, reward
    #-------------------------------------------------

    class DQNAgent:
        def __init__(self, state_size, action_size):
            self.state_size = state_size
            self.action_size = action_size
            self.memory = deque(maxlen=2000)
            self.gamma = 0.95    # discount rate
            self.epsilon = 1.0  # exploration rate
            self.epsilon_min = 0.01
            self.epsilon_decay = 0.995
            self.learning_rate = 0.001
            self.model = self._build_model()

        def _build_model(self):
            # Neural Net for Deep-Q learning Model
            model = Sequential()
            model.add(Dense(24, input_dim=self.state_size, activation='relu'))
            model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
            model.add(Dense(self.action_size, activation='linear'))
            model.compile(loss='mse',
                          optimizer=Adam(lr=self.learning_rate))
            return model

        def remember(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
            self.memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))

        def act(self, state):
            if np.random.rand() <= self.epsilon:
                return random.randrange(self.action_size)
            act_values = self.model.predict(state)
            return np.argmax(act_values[0])  # returns action

        def replay(self, batch_size):
            minibatch = random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)
            for state, action, reward, next_state, done in minibatch:
                target = reward
                if not done:
                    target = (reward + self.gamma *
                              np.amax(self.model.predict(next_state)[0]))
                target_f = self.model.predict(state)
                target_f[0][action] = target
                self.model.fit(state, target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0)
            if self.epsilon > self.epsilon_min:
                self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay

        def load(self, name):
            self.model.load_weights(name)

        def save(self, name):
            self.model.save_weights(name)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        #env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')
        #state_size = env.observation_space.shape[0]
        #action_size = env.action_space.n

        state_size=4
        action_size=5
        agent = DQNAgent(state_size, action_size)
        # agent.load("./save/cartpole-dqn.h5")
        done = False
        batch_size = 32

        for e in range(episodes):
            state = env.reset()
            state = np.reshape(state, [1, state_size])
            for time in range(500):
                # env.render()
                action = agent.act(state)
                next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
                reward = reward if not done else -10
                next_state = np.reshape(next_state, [1, state_size])
                agent.remember(state, action, reward, next_state, done)
                state = next_state
                if done:
                    print("episode: {}/{}, score: {}, e: {:.2}"
                          .format(e, EPISparam2DES, time, agent.epsilon))
                    break
            if len(agent.memory) > batch_size:
                agent.replay(batch_size)
            # if e % 10 == 0:
            #     agent.save("./save/cartpole-dqn.h5")

            agent = DQNAgent(state_size, action_size)
            # agent.load("./save/cartpole-dqn.h5")


  [1]: https://github.com/keon/deep-q-learning/blob/master/dqn.py
```

Answer (score 0):

The DQN algorithm you linked to is for a single agent game. You have to change it quite a bit to work with multiple agents. There are [multiple](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.06676v2.pdf) [papers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.04402) written on the subject. If you want to truly understand what your code is doing, I suggest finding a paper that tries to solve an environment similar to yours and then applying the concepts within that paper to your code.